# Measures on a Borel sigma algebra...

Tags: real-analysis

If we have two measures which are equal on the open intervals in the real line, and the Borel sigma algebra on the standard topology is the collection being measured, why must the two measures be equivalent?

I have shown quite easily that they are equal on all open and closed sets, and am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: The set of subsets of R on which the two measures agree is a sigma-algebra that contains the open intervals. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Why is it a sigma algebra?

Comment: Show that they're equal on half-open intervals, partition R into (an infinite number of) finite half-open intervals, and apply additivity.

Comment: I have shown they are equal on half open intervals, but I do not see how your suggestion is helping any. You have shown essentially that the two measures agree on the whole space, which I already knew because the whole space is open and closed.

Comment: My previous comment is what it takes to show that "the set of subsets on which the measures agree" is closed under complement. It should be much easier to show that that set is closed under countable unions.

Comment: So the set in question is a sigma algebra since the measures agree on the complement (since they agree on the whole space, since the whole space is open, and the measures agree on open sets). Then it is closed under countable unions since countable unions can be broken up into disjoint countable unions, and on each piece the measures agree, thus they agree on the union. Is this correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10518/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-johnny-apple)

Comment: you need the measure to be sigma finite, else there is a counterexample below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may not be equivalent. Take counting measure and counting measure times $2$. Each interval gets infinite measure under both measures, but they differ on finite sets.